# xamarin-form: Can we add overlay to xam.plugins.media

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, camera

I am using xam.plugin.media package to handle capturing photos. I can capture the photos but want to have a overlay on top of the camera.

The overlay work for iOS but not available on android.

Is there a way to extend the package and to have android working?

I also found a site helping me to create a camera :

https://thatcsharpguy.com/post/full-camera-page.1/

This works fine on iOS, possibly on android (haven't not tried).

This document uses the old Camera api not Camera2 api to create the camera, so I can't use this. I would prefer to use latest Camera api.

Comment: Do you mean add a overlay on the top of camera or also need to add it on the top of photos?

Comment: Add the overlay to camera

Comment: Ok , if not using `xam.plugin.media` ,it will be easy to do that in native method.

Comment: `xam.plugins.media` is not supported `overlay`  for Xamain.Android.You can post a issue to here.(https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues)